# Why does the page jump to the bottom on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on this bootstrap/jquery [page](http://1783-6934.el-alt.com/Locations/Branch?BranchID=6) in Firefox (v39, current as of writing), the page jumps to the bottom.

I looked at the code and I don't see any Javascript to make it do so.  Nor do I see any CSS that's obvious.

What am I missing?

P.S.  In Chrome, it only acts like Firefox if the browser width is less than 1300 pixels.  I assume it crosses the bootstrap layout boundary.

Comment: Disable scripts one by one until the behaviour goes away.

Comment: May be the focus in on google maps so it is going down. Try giving focus to search text box on page load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of your contact Us form. If you CTRL + F5 you will see how during page load the name field is visible and getting the keyboard focus.

After that it is hidden but the page remains when the focus was for the last time, and that is at the bottom of the page.

To solve it try hiding the tabs by default at the very beginning before the onload is executed.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  You are right.  I didn't notice `<input autofocus="true"`.  Much obliged.

Comment: You're welcome. It's my pleasure to help someone with such reputation.